# Can I use l'Hôpital's rule on this?

Tags: calculus, limits

Question:

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\cos x}$

This was in a set of questions about l'Hôpital's rule.

However, the numerator is undefined and the denominator equals $0.5$ at $x$ rather than $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$. How would I solve this?

Comment: $\cos(\pi/2)=0$. Why 0.5?

Comment: Oh what. I didn't have a calculator on hand and google told me it was .5. thanks!

P.S. since the top is undefined does that mean I can treat it as 0? Since it approaches 0.

Comment: Likewise $\ln \sin (\pi/2) = \ln 1 = 0$.  Also, Windows has a calculator, `calc.exe`.

Comment: @user3362196 Google told you it was $0.5$? Strange—I typed `cos(pi/2)` into Google just now, and it gave me $0$. (Perhaps you accidentally typed it `cos(pi/3)`?)

Answer (score 4):

Both the numerator and the denominator are $0$, so it is an indeterminate form. If you are unsure about this, look at the sine and cosine waves.

You can apply L'Hopital's rule to the function:

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\cos(x)}=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x \times -\sin x}=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}$$.

Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\cos(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(x)}{-\sin^2(x)}
$$

Therefore

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}-\cot(x) \csc(x) = -\cot(\frac{\pi}{2}) \csc(\frac{\pi}{2})= 0
$$

Comment: Hmm are you sure? My prof says that it should be 0.

Comment: I did it wrong at first, sorry for the confusion

Comment: What's the point in using the cosecant and the cotangent? It's just unnecessary complication: $\cos(\pi/2)=0$ and $-\sin^2(\pi/2)=-1$.

Comment: @egreg What do you mean?

$$
\frac{\cos(x)}{-\sin^2(x)} = -\cot(x) \csc(x)
$$

Comment: I have a habit of expanding things out like so, its another perspective and it doesn't hurt.

Comment: If a student cannot understand why simplifying trig functions is useful then I don't think the student is paying much attention in the class. I don't see why this is such a big deal.

Comment: You're missing my point, it seems. OK; I'll leave only my first comment that explains it.